# JDBC login with Jpype

Tags: java, python, jdbc, jpype, jaydebeapi

While the below snippet works

```
import jaydebeapi
conn = jaydebeapi.connect('com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver',['jdbc:teradata://hostname/TMODE=TERA,CHARSET=utf8', 'username', 'password'],['/var/jar_files/tdgssconfig.jar','/var/jar_files/terajdbc4.jar'])
```

This doesn't. I am getting authentication failure.

```
import jaydebeapi,jpype
jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(),'-Djava.ext.dirs=/var/jar_files/')
conn = jaydebeapi.connect('com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver',['jdbc:teradata://hostname/TMODE=TERA,CHARSET=utf8', 'username', 'password'],)
```

This is the stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jaydebeapi/dbapi2.py", line 324, in connect
    jconn = _jdbc_connect(jclassname, jars, libs, *driver_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jaydebeapi/dbapi2.py", line 148, in _jdbc_connect_jpype
    return jpype.java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(*driver_args)
jpype._jexception.JDBCExceptionPyRaisable: com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 14.00.00.37] [Error 8017] [SQLState 28000] The UserId, Password or Account is invalid.
```

I have confirmed multiple times that the username,password is accurate.

Comment: Please consult the Teradata manual on what parameters to pass to the JDBC connect method. Does it have the username as the first and password as the second param. Or do you have to specify them in a different way? jaydebeapi's contract that it passes the parameters 1:1 to the JDBC connect method.

Comment: Ok,now i see the second one uses different user and password

Comment: thanks @bastian I ended up using the first version. AFAIK the second version is supposed to work. take a look at a sample code for Teradata JDBC connectivity at https://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samp/T20000JD.java.txt.  specifically the signature of getConnection(url, sUser, sPassword) method